# Will MutationObserver detect changes loaded through external style sheet?

Tags: javascript, android-webview, mutation-observers, external-js

I have added a mutationObserver to a div identified by the class name. The code snippet is given below.

```
var target = document.getElemenstsByClassName('uniqueClassName')[0];

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation){
console.log('mutation happened');});

var config = {attributes:true};

observer.observe(target,config);
```

The HTML page has an external style sheet which holds some styles for our target which is div, is mentioned below.

```
.uniqueClassName{
  height: 468px;
  width: 549px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url("../images/page007.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And we need to fetch the URL for the image once the content is loaded. But the statements inside the mutation observer doesn't get called (currently a log).

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/font.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/page004005.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=549, height=468"/>
<title>page004005</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div class="page">
<div class="uniqueClassName">

<article class="page_7_block_0">
</article>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you haven't posted your html div code, it is difficult to tell what exactly is causing the issue. However, try adding `characterData: true` to your config .

Comment: Your `config` doesn't have `subtree: true` so it reports only HTML attributes on the node itself. Anyway, CSS is irrelevant and not handled by MutationObserver except when specified in `style="...."` HTML attribute according the config you use.

Comment: @Agalo I have added the HTML code. Pls have a look.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there any other way to identify when the external js loading completes?

Comment: It depends on how that file is loaded. There are many answers for this question, which you can easily find using Google search or a similar site.

Comment: @wOxxOm the external file is specified as <link> in the head tag. And am loading the content in a webview in android. Tried searching for solutions but couldnt find any valid ones.

Comment: `link` doesn't execute js files, it can only load CSS files and preload resources. At this point I still don't understand what you actually want. The things you describe just don't add up.

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry, I meant CSS file. I just need to make sure that the styles specified in the css sheet gets loaded before i perform operations on the div. Right now, by the time I try to fetch the backgroung image url (being added from the external css) its not yet loaded.

Comment: Ah, MutationObserver won't help. There are other [known techniques](https://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/).